# Preventing SQL Injection In Ibatis

Tags: java, sql, mysql, ibatis

Is there anything built into Ibatis that helps prevent SQL Injection attacks? I'm not looking for a list of ways outside of Ibatis to do this, and am just wondering if Ibatis has anything to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IBatis uses JDBC prepared statements under the hood and is therefore safe. However this only applies if your use the `#` notation. It's also possible to concat variables directly into your query using the `$` notation which is not safe (unless you escape them). See [this article](https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/sql_injection_ibatis_data_map.html) for background info.

Answer (score -3):

I'd guess iBatis is using prepared statements, and parameter binding, so it's safe.

Comment: -1 - guessing for something as sensitive as a SQL Injection entry point

Comment: It's not safe when using $ notation